# Dynamically change knitr .Rmd report text

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to dynamically change the text of an R markdown report template I'm using depending on certain inputs. I'm calling knitr from the PowerShell.

This is the input I would like to insert into the R markdown text Input:

```
{
  "start": "1/21/2015",
  "end": "1/23/2015",
  "species: ["RBHS", "DBHS", "CBHS"]
}
```

.Rmd file

````
---
title: "Capture Report"
author: "Mitchell Gritts"
date: Sys.Date()
output: html_document
---

```{r load packages, include = FALSE}
LoadScripts()
```

## Capture Table

All SPECIESLIST captured between STARTDATE and ENDDATE are included 
in the table. Data included in the table are Species, NDOW ID, Sex, Age, 
Marks and Collar information.
````

SPECIESLIST, STARTDATE and ENDDATE are to be replaced with the values from the input.

Is there a way to do this with `knitr` or `sweave`. Or do I use search and replace functions to do this?

Comment: Where is this json input and how do you want to call knitr? You could, e.g., have your Rmd document read the json from a file somewhere. Or if you've read the json object into your global environment, calling `knit` from the console (not from the RStudio button) you can reference global vars. Or you can use `brew` [as here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14968164/903061).

Comment: I've removed the JSON reference as what I meant was the input code box, and updated how I would like to call knitr. Brew is not an option as I must comply with IT rules.

Comment: HAve you looked at brew? https://botthoughts.wordpress.com/

Comment: The [parametrized reports documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) at RStudio might be helpful.