# How to print and combine text that is stored in a dataframe?

Tags: r, knitr

I have a dataframe like follows:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf <- data_frame(headline = c('this is the first news',
                                'this is the second news'),
                   fulltext = c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum',
                                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum'))
```

essentially, I would like to create a document (`pdf`, `html`, whatever) that for each article, prints the `headline` followed by the 100 first characters from the `fulltext` column.

Something like

-- start of `html/pdf` output

**this is the first news**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident

**this is the second news**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident

-- end of `html/pdf` output

How can I do that with `knitr`?

Comment: Related: [how to create a loop that includes both a code chunk and text with knitr in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373630/how-to-create-a-loop-that-includes-both-a-code-chunk-and-text-with-knitr-in-r); [Create parametric R markdown documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959312/create-parametric-r-markdown-documentation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of a `for` loop, `cat`, and the chunk option `results = 'asis'`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
mydf <- data_frame(headline = c('this is the first news',
                                'this is the second news'),
                   fulltext = c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum',
                                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum'))
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
for (i in seq_len(nrow(mydf))){
  cat(paste0("**", mydf[["headline"]][i], "**"))
  cat("\n\n")
  cat(
    paste0(
      gsub("\\n", "\n\n", substr(mydf[["fulltext"]][i], 1, 100), "...")
    )
  )
  cat("\n\n")
}
```
````

Comment: very nice! but this solution does not seem to take into account any possible `\n` included in the full text. do you see some easy fix here? thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the `\n` in `fulltext`?  Should that create a new paragraph, or be ignored?

Comment: ideally, new paragraph. OBEY what is written in the full text that is :D

Comment: Edited the answer:  It's crude, but it replaces any instance of `\n` with `\n\n` (you need two line breaks to make a new paragraph in markdown.  If this creates excessive line breaks in the markdown, it should get ignored as unnecessary whitespace).

Answer (score 2):

You really want to use the knitr for some reason? A poor way to do this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mydf)){
  temp=(paste(mydf[i,1],'<br>','\n',mydf[i,2]))
  write.table(temp,paste(i,'.txt'), row.names = F,col.names = F)
  knit(paste(i,'.txt'),paste(i,'.html'))
}
```

Comment: not necessarily knitr. Any good way to output this would be good. text can contain characters such as \n newlines